# Can I save rice cereal for a baby for short periods of time?

Tags: infant, solids

We've started feeding our baby rice cereal. I try to make small amounts and make more if he needs it, but sometimes I make too much.

I understand that once you've prepared rice cereal (mixed it with breast milk), you can't really put it in the fridge and save it. But is it ok to save it for an hour or two? (I just tried to feed him and he wasn't hungry. He'll probably be hungry in about an hour or so. Can I save it till then?)

Comment: I don't know if you "can" but I have noticed that rice cereal gets more and more runny as it sits...

Comment: I think this belongs on http://cooking.stackexchange.com and isn't really on topic here. =\

Comment: @AarthiDevanathan: I don't think _cooking.SE_ would care for questions that basically deal with infant health concerns. I think it's perfectly on-topic here.

Answer (score 5):

I would treat it like breastmilk, myself.

Follow the [usual guidelines](http://www.cdc.gov/breastfeeding/recommendations/handling_breastmilk.htm) for how long you can keep breastmilk out at room temperature.  Most sources say it's okay for up to 6 hours, if your house isn't too warm.

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on if you are using breastmilk or formula to mix the cereal. Check the recommendations.  Remember that if it has come into contact with your baby's saliva then it should be used or disgarded more quickly than if you mix it in different container than you use for feeding.